# What is meaning of "kullerleicht"?

Tags: meaning

Here are lines from children book:

> "Vorher wollen wir noch darüber sprechen, wie all unsere Körperteile heißen."
>
> "Aber das ist doch kullerleicht", denkt Lisa.

What is meaning of word *kullerleicht*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the word and I don't think it really exist. I think it is a new word creation. If you search at [Google](http://www.google.de/search?q=kullerleicht) you find the word in a children song. In children songs you often find this kind of new phantasy words.

Google’s NGram Viewer doesn’t know it, too: [Google Ngram Viewer: kullerleicht& declination forms](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Kullerleicht%2Ckullerleicht%2Ckullerleichte%2Ckullerleichter%2Ckullerleichtes%2Ckullerleichten%2Ckullerleichtem&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=50&share=).

It's a combination of [`kinderleicht`](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&searchLocRelinked=1&search=kinderleicht) (very easy) and [`kullern`](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kullern) (to roll around). `Kullerleicht` is as easy as to roll around. Another source could be a game with [marbles](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kuller)

There is also a word [`Kuller`](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuller) (a part of a plane), but I don't think there is a relation to `kullerleicht`.